# How can I get Emacs to release a locking folder handle?

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient, file-locking

After using Emacs to open a file in a folder on MS Windows using `emacsclientw -n`, killing the buffer does not release a handle Emacs has to the folder, so the folder can't be deleted.

```
GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)
Windows 10 v1909
Explorer context menu entry: C:\Program Files\Emacs\bin\emacsclientw -a "C:\Progra~1\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe" -n "%1"
```

How can I get Emacs to release the containing folder handle?